# Install application without Google Play

Tags: installation, apk

I made an [application](http://elv.locky.jp/app), and I want my friend to install it from a link, but the apk file cannnot be installed on the Android phone. He has to use some file explorer to install it. But I see many apps can be installed from a link and installed directly without using the file explorer.

What should I do to my APK? Is it a signature problem?

Comment: This is most likely a programming question. Please see this related question in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062685/download-and-install-apk-from-a-link

Comment: @geff_chang Installing an app from a link is one thing, doing so programmatically is another -- I don't think the latter is the case here.  Tianhui, I think it probably depends on his device or browser.  What happens when he clicks the link to your app, does the browser just download it?

Comment: @MatthewRead I am using play framework, browser just download a APK file.I signed the APK, but I still cannot use the web browser(original browser) to install it. I think the problem is my APK file or server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally phones should be able to install apps even if they are not signed. Normally your friend should be able to install your app. I was able to download the application, and I could also start the installation from the link.

Make sure that your friends phone has 'unknown sources' enabled in the security menu (enable Settings > Security > Unknown Sources). Because otherwise it will also not work (without using Google Play == unknown source).

No offense though, but I didn't test all the way through the installation, because I don't trust it well enough and I have no idea what the app actually does. For all I know it is a virus ;-)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have tried to make my application to be signed, but the problem still remain. I saw this http://www.droidforums.net/forum/tech-issues-bug-reports-suggestions/2061-content-not-supported.html

Comment: And change the sever 's setheader from Content-Disposition to text/plain , but the problem still remain. I try to use other broswer, such as firefox, the problem solved. But I see some other APK could be installed from the web without using firefox. I think there is some thing wrong with my APK or Server.

Comment: @TianhuiYang If Firefox can install it then the problem shouldn't be with the APK.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to send the apk. file via bluetooth or via email. But if it doesn't work at all, go to settings>>Security>>Unknown Sources (enabled)... beacuse apk. is a non-market apps.

Comment: Sending an apk with Bluetooth will not work as there's a filter in place based on type of file that can be transferred, txt, jpeg, png, mp4, but not apk's for security reasons.

Comment: The only trick that can be done, is to rename the apk to png or jpg, then it can be sent across (ssshhhh, that's a security hole in there! ;) )